# OutOfMemoryError in getView() with progressbar

Tags: android, android-listview, out-of-memory, android-progressbar

I have a `ListView` with each items containing a `ProgressBar` and an `ImageButton`. But in some devices, OutOfMemoryError occurs in the `getView()` implementation of the list's adapter. Here's the [full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/DNeqbH01).

The line where the error occurs is given below:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        if (mDrawable == null)
            mDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress);

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_list_item, parent, false); // The crash occurs here.
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        holder.progressBarEpisodes.setProgressDrawable(mDrawable);
    }


    // Show season name.
    refreshProgress(position, holder);

    ...

}


private void refreshProgress(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.progressBarEpisodes.setMax(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getTotal()));
    holder.progressBarEpisodes.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getProgress()));
}
```

My layout xml for list item is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        ....

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:progress="50"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/EpisodeActionButton"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector_no_alpha"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, I've customized the progress bar style like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/gray_500"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/secondary_500" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Can you please help me with a solution of this crash problem?

Comment: What kind of phone are you testing on? Having a progress bar updating in every row of a listview sounds pretty taxing in terms of memory.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't able to recreate the crash in any of my device. The crash was reported by Crashlytics in HTC One and SYMPHONY W130 (XPLORERW130)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at this part of your stack trace:

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)

It looks to me like each time you inflate the view it's trying to get a new version of this bitmap that you're displaying.  My recommendation would be to set that bitmap programatically, and reuse the same bitmap over and over so that you're not loading multiple versions of it into memory at the same time.

How many of these guys are you loading up?  If you want to load multiple different images should try caching them using:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Try to reuse, cache and release resources efficiently.

Comment: Thanks @Nathaniel. I tried doing that but it behaves strangely since all the progress bar in the list items have the same `Drawable`. All the progressbars are changing at the sametime with the same progress. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Could you post more code relating to how you're storing view references (holders) and how you're updating the progress bars?

Comment: Sure. Please check the code in the question. I've updated it.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I was talking about the drawable for the ImageButton, not the progress bar drawable.

Comment: Why don't you move the line below into adapter's constructor? if (mDrawable == null)
            mDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress);

Comment: Thanks again @NathanielWaggoner. I have changed the button drawable implementation as you suggested. But looking at the stack trace, it seems like the error is coming from the progressbar, isn't it?